# GIT - invalid revision range in local repositories

Tags: git, githooks

I'm trying to force commits to include Jira ticket ID with pre-receive hook. To test it locally I'm using repository as server-side, so I ran:

`git init --bare server` - in `hooks/pre-receive` I added logic to check if commit starts with [TICKET_ID] or [NA]. When I clone repository `git clone server client` and if commit doesn't include this ticket I need to edit commit message, so I use: `git rebase -i COMMIT_HASH^`, then I need to change `pick` to `reword`, edit commit message and `git push`. As it can be really annoying I want to add `prepare-commit-msg` hook to automatically add ticket from branch name , which looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Include any branches for which you wish to disable this script
if [ -z "$BRANCHES_TO_SKIP" ]; then
  BRANCHES_TO_SKIP=(master develop staging test)
fi
# Get the current branch name and check if it is excluded
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
BRANCH_EXCLUDED=$(printf "%s\n" "${BRANCHES_TO_SKIP[@]}" | grep -c "^$BRANCH_NAME$")
# Trim it down to get the parts we're interested in
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -e 's:^\([^-]*-[^-]*\)-.*:\1:' -e \
    'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/')
# If it isn't excluded, preprend the trimmed branch identifier to the given message
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ] &&  ! [[ $BRANCH_EXCLUDED -eq 1 ]]; then
  sed -i.bak -e "1s/^/$TRIMMED /" $1
fi
```

When I want to push changes: `git push --set-upstream origin AZ-0987-test` I'm getting error:

```
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 5 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 302 bytes | 302.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: fatal: Invalid revision range 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000..c15f3a1cb5875d944c8affcdec31f8b06a7e3ac4
To /home/user/just-testing/server/
 * [new branch]      AZ-0987-test -> AZ-0987-test
Branch 'AZ-0987-test' set up to track remote branch 'AZ-0987-test' from 'origin'.
```

And `git log --oneline` return this:
[image]

Could somebody tell me what went wrong or what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT - Steps to reproduce my problem

- run `git init --bare server`
- configure `server/hooks/pre-receive` with:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Jira ticket pattern
# JIRA_TICKET_PATTERN="[A-Z]+-[0-9]+"
# (^\[NA\])|(^\[[A-Z]{2,}-\d+\])
JIRA_TICKET_PATTERN="(^\[NA\])|(\[[A-Z]+-[0-9]+\])"

# Read the new references from standard input
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
  # Iterate over the new commits
  for commit in $(git rev-list ${oldrev}..${newrev}); do
    # Get the commit message
    message=$(git log --format=%B -n 1 ${commit})

    # Check if the commit message already contains a Jira ticket number
    if [[ ${message} =~ ${JIRA_TICKET_PATTERN} ]]; then
        echo "Commit ${commit} already contains a [Jira ticket number] or [NA]: ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    else
        echo "MESSAGE ${message}"
        echo "ERROR:"
        echo "ERROR: Your push was rejected because the commit"
        echo "ERROR: $commit in ${refname#refs/heads/}"
        echo "ERROR: is missing the JIRA Issue, for example: '[MM-1234] msg' or '[NA] msg'."
        echo "ERROR:"
        echo "ERROR: Please fix the commit message and push again."
        echo "ERROR: https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-commit-message"
        echo "ERROR"
        exit 1
    fi
  done
```

- clone repository with: `git clone server client`
- create file, add file, commit with wrong message - you should get error
- change commit message - run `git rebase -i COMMIT^`, change `pick>reword`, save, change commit message , [AB-1234] message, save
- git push - it should work now
- in .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg (in cloned repository) paste script from my question
- run `git branch -b SO-987654-test-brach`
- add file, commit without any ticker in msg - ticker should be added automatically, push changes
- you should see an error

Comment: The first thing to do is to narrow down which line in your bash script causes the error. I recommend adding echo commands to help narrow this down.

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but I would have used `git commit --amend` instead of a rebase and reword, since it seems like you're just editing the last commit.

Comment: To address your actual question, I'm not sure you've given us enough information. Your `git log` seems to suggest the push actually worked, despite the error message, for one thing. What do you see on the simulated remote side? It might help if you can provide a complete (but minimal!) example we could copy-paste on our own machines and reproduce on our side.

Comment: @joanis I can't use `git commit --amend`, because somebody can make multiple commits without push, so later he needs to pick commits to change message.

Comment: @joanis I added steps to reproduce my problem, hope it's clear otherwise let me know I will explain in with more details

Comment: When the oldrev is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, it means a new branch is to be created. When the newrev is the zeros, it means a branch is to be deleted. In these 2 cases, you can't use the commit range. I think you can just ignore the branch deletion. For the branch creation, you could ignore it or use `git rev-list $newrev` to get all the commits.

Answer (score 3):

Your pre-receive isn't checking for new branches, you're just using `$old..$new` or some equivalent, which won't work except in restricted situations.

```
#!/bin/bash --
# pre-receive hook to vet all inbound commits not in existing history

# collect all non-deleted tips, *[^0]* is any string w/ a nonzero
while read old new ref; do
    incoming+=("$old $new $ref")
    [[ $new = *[^0]* ]] && news+=($new)
done

# vet each commit, id's via here-doc to keep shell environ access
while read commit; do
    check $commit here || hookrc=1
done <<EOD
$(  git rev-list ${news[@]} --not --all )
EOD

exit $hookrc
```

(note: the Mac ships with a criminally-neglected bash install, you'll need the [`brew install bash`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24632/is-it-safe-to-upgrade-bash-via-homebrew) version.)

Comment: I understand your point, but I think I have problem to know which pare of script should be changed